# Django auto Mail

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to learn django for the past couple of days, and I've made a basic bug tracking software as of now (using the admin part of django) 
Ive created a table called bugs:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Bugs(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ('Work In Progress', 'Work In Progress'),
        ('Incomplete', 'Incomplete'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed')
    )
    Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Basic_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Detailed_Description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
    Assigned_to = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    Reporters_Mail_ID = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    Reported_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    Deadline_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Project_Name + ' [' + self.Status + '] ' + self.Basic_Description + ' [' + self.Assigned_to + ']'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bugs"
```

How do I make it so that when a project name is selected, the `Assigned_to` is also automatically selected?

And how do I make sure that once it is assigned to the person/ Status is edited/ or any sort of edit is made by the `SuperUser`, a mail is sent to the person it is assigned to, and when an edit is made by the `Person` it is assigned to, the super user gets a mail saying an edit has been made?

**Not that important but,** *I was also wondering if there is any way to make sure that when the Super user Assigns some work to one of the admins, Only the admin specified can view the Issue??*

**UPDATE:**

Let me try to be more descriptive this time..

So i have 2 types of users:
1st is the Super User who decides what bugs should be placed into the list and also manages the other users as well.
2nd is the other normal users, selected by the superuser (Users can only edit the posts added by the superuser)

The database has 12 columns out of which `Project_Name` and `Assigned_To` are 2.

My question is,

How do I make it such that when the superuser enters the `Project_Name`, the `Assigned_To` Column is already filled?

take this as an example

```
Project_Name: Project1 ---> Assigned_To: Person1
Project_Name: Project2 ---> Assigned_To: Person2
Project_Name: Project3 ---> Assigned_To: Person3
Project_Name: Project4 ---> Assigned_To: Person4
```

Now if the Super User Decides that the bug is in Project 1, and Project 1 is handled by Person 1, How do i make the program such that If Project 1 is chosen, Person 1 will automatically be selected in the `Assigned_To` Column?

And Once the SuperUser Selects the SAVE option(taking the same case as above). How do I make the program send a mail to Person1 when ever SuperUser Updates the database? And how do I make the program send a mail to the SuperUser when the Person1 Makes changes to the Database?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what your questions really are, but as I understood, you first need to add another field for user as following :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), blank=True, null=True)
```

regarding sending email when an object of the model is saved or updated, you should override the save() method of the model and put the code you want to execute.

Comment: Hey, I've Updated the Post, please have a look at it and let me know what you think? And Could you please elaborate on what you mean by
"l when an object of the model is saved or updated, you should override the save() method of the model and put the code you want to execute" 
I Started learning Django Just a little while ago, So i dont know much about it..

Comment: you have two options: 1)Assigned_to should have a ForeignKey to django User model (already explained) 2) create another model for Project and add it related fields like assigned_to

Answer (score 0):

You can use django signals, 
When the SuperUser saves or edits. You can write your code to achieve whatever you want.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save  

def send_email(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # your code goes here...

post_save.connect(send_email, sender=Bugs)
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first off, it's common practice to use all lower case for model fields. Python has a style guide called PEP8 which documents all the best practices for writing python. So take a look here to get started; https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles

Now if your `assigned_to` model should reference a user for the model to relate to you should indeed do as Milad said & use a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model because there are many benefits to using relationships where it makes sense for your data.

If you want the `assigned_to` to be automatically filled based on the `project_name` then you'd have to use javascript. You'd probably send an AJAX request on selection of the project to go to the backend with the project value. Then send back the assignee for that project which would be used in the javascript to set the value of the `assigned_to` field.

As far as sending emails go when changes are made to your model, you should use signals in python. [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) get fired when changes are made to objects, for example;

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from bugs.models import Bugs


@receiver(post_save, sender=Bugs)
def bugs_post_save(sender, instance=None, created=None, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
    if created or 'assigned_to' in update_fields:
        # We have a new object or the assignee has changed
        send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com',
            ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

The docs on email sending are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/)

Your receiver functions like this can be included underneath your models or in a specific `signals.py` module which you'd import in the [application config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#module-django.apps). That would like something like;

```
# bugs/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class BugsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'bugs'
    verbose_name = "Bugs"

    def ready(self):
        # importing signals
        import signals
```